# Adding two fileinfo[] together

Tags: c#, fileinfo

```
FileInfo[] comList = new FileInfo[]{};
FileInfo[] files
DirectoryInfo dInfo;
string[] folderList = path.Split(',');
foreach (string folder in folderList){
    dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
    files = dInfo.GetFiles().Where(F => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
    comList.Concat(files);
}
```

I am trying to read multiple folders and get all the files into one FileInfo[], but after doing the concat to comList, my comList is still empty.

the path input is something like `string path = "pathA,pathB,pathC"`
if this is not the way to do it, what is a better ways to get all the files from different directory into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netcore-3.1) `Concat` will returns a new collection without modifying existing one:

```cs
public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource> (
  this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> first, 
  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> second);
```

Therefore in your scenario assigning the statement back to `comList` as following and you're good to go!

```cs
comList = comList.Concat(files);
```

Nonetheless, if you're not constraining yourself to use array for `comList`, you may consider to use `List` instead which allow us to achieve the same without redundant cast:

```cs
List<FileInfo> comList = new List<FileInfo>();
...
foreach (string folder in folderList) {
   var dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
   var files = dInfo.GetFiles().Where(f => 
                 extensions.Contains(
                   f.Extension.ToLower()));

   comList.AddRange(files);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the return of [comList.Concat(files)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netcore-3.1), like:

```
comList = comList.Concat(files).ToArray();
```

The `ToArray()` method is needed because `Concat()` returns an `IEnumerable`.
Alternatively you can make `comList` an actual `List<FileInfo>` and use its [AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netcore-3.1) method in each iteration:

```
comList.AddRange(files);
```

Comment: We have got similar thoughts here!